# JSTL forEach loop prints in unexpected order

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl

I wish to print a screen and afterwards a bunch of seats:

mgi =img

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<HTML>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    </head>


<body dir="rtl">

    <%@  taglib        prefix="c"   uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" %>




 <table border="0" style="width: 100%" dir="rtl">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" >
                    <p align="center">
                        <mgi src="${initParam.seatsPath}theater_screen.jpg" alt="Screen"/></a>

                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>

                             <c:forEach var="seat" items="${seatsList}" varStatus="iter">

                             <c:if test="${seat.seatColumn == 1}"> <tr><td> ${seat.seatRow} </td>  </c:if>

                             <c:choose>
                                    <c:when test="${seat.status==3}"> <mgi src="${initParam.seatsPath}seat_taken.jpg" id="seat_${seat.seatRow}_${seat.seatColumn}" style=" padding-right: 2px; vertical-align: middle;" alt="מושב תפוס" /></a>  </c:when>
                                    <c:otherwise> <mgi src="${initParam.seatsPath}seat_clear.jpg" id="seat_${seat.seatRow}_${seat.seatColumn}" onclick="clickSeat(${seat.seatPK.id}, ${seat.seatRow}, ${seat.seatColumn})" style=" padding-right: 2px; vertical-align: middle;" alt="מושב פנוי" /></a>  </c:otherwise>
                             </c:choose>

                             <c:if test="${seat.seatColumn == seatsPerRow}"> </td><td> ${seat.seatRow} </td></tr>  </c:if>

                        </c:forEach>


</table>


</body>
</HTML>
```

but what i get is this:

seats

screen

seats rows (printed by the (c:if...) tag)

Sorry as my reputation is too low to upload a clarifying image

Comment: solved it... missing <td align="center"> at the end of the first if inside the loop.

Comment: You can either answer your question and accept it. or delete this question. first one is better

Answer (score 0):

it turned out to be more of a html question as a `<td align="center">` was missing at the first if inside the loop.

this is the full if:

```
 <c:if test="${seat.seatColumn == 1}"> <tr><td> ${seat.seatRow} </td><td align="center">  </c:if>
```